# ShopifyError: Cannot initialize Shopify API Library. Missing values for: apiSecretKey, hostName, apiKey, scopes

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

Here is the code I have while setting my Node js app with Shopify.
Do you have same issue?

```
const shopifynew = shopifyApi({
    apiKey: "1765318888888888",
    apiSecretKey: "86c064d15ab72a8888888888888",
    scopes: ["read_products"],
    hostName: "ngrok-tunnel-addr888,
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    isEmbeddedApp: false,
});
```

I want to initialize the Nodejs app according to the new updated docs: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-api](https://stackoverflow.com)

Error Message: [Cannot initialize Shopify API Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJIvm.png)

Comment: You have your API key in the post. I would definitely delete this post entirely because history can also be looked at as well. (Or just reset your key and edit the post)

Answer (score 2):

In the node template of shopify app. There are 3 folders containing package.json

Main > Web > Frontend

in simple words

Shopify App > Backend ( Node ) > Frontend ( React )

In the Web folder there are **index.js** and **shopify.js**.

You need to install a package **dotenv** and import the same package in both said files like

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

after importing you need to create a **.env** file in the web folder with these keys

- SHOPIFY_API_KEY
- SHOPIFY_API_SECRET
- HOST
- SCOPES

if you are still stuck please update your question.

Just one warning, Please donot share **API_KEY AND SECRET_KEY IN THE QUESTION**, just put my api key , my secret key instead.

I will edit the question for now.